# Is it possible to insert an icon in title bar in Xamarin Forms - UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms

In UWP, Toolbar items is shown at the bottom. My question is, is it possible to insert icon in Navigation bar for xamarin.forms - UWP. I want an icon to be displayed is Navigation bar/Title bar is all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way to do this directly in XAML, but in your code (app would be best) you can check if UWP and then use [CoreApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication)

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar
```